# I want to make a website for my company and make it server rendering just in order to have good seo support. Is gatsy proper for it?

Tags: gatsby

I would like to make website for my company which should have following features

1. Be server-side rendering
2. Be blazing fast.
3. Be proper for Search Engine Optimization
4. Easily maintainance

Can you please let me know if gatsby is a good option for this requirement and how to make my website server side rendering in gatsby ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Gatsby is proper for your requirements.

The official documentation has lots of information to [push SEO on your Gatsby site](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/seo/).

I would advise to

1. go through the [tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/)
2. then pick a [pre-built starter project with SEO already implemented](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/?c=SEO&v=2) and keep building your site.